# requests over https keep-alive until a good response (perl or python2.7)

Tags: perl, python-2.7, http, https, keep-alive

I would like to keep sending some HTTP requests over an `https` `Keep-Alive` connection until I get a good response (e.g., a response matching a certain string/regex).

What would be the best way to do this in `perl` or `python2.7`?  (I'm a C programmer, don't know much Perl or Python.)

Answer (score 1):

> If you're building a web application that might be deployed in a high
>   network latency situation, consider taking advantage of HTTP/1.1
>   Keep-Alive. This requires that you build up the HTML that your CGI
>   will emit, and then emit the HTML in one piece, with a Content-Length
>   prepended. Something along the lines of
>
> ```
> binmode(STDOUT);
> $html = ...;
> print "Content-Type: text/html\r\n",
>       "Content-Length: ", length($html), "\r\n\r\n",
>       $html;
> ```
>
> or, if using CGI,
>
> ```
> $html = ...;
> print header(-content_length => length($html)), $html;
> ```
>
> will do the trick.

Read more at: [Keep-Alive and Perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=83791)

Modern web frameworks already provide option to `keep-alive`. For example in `Mojo::Server::Hypnotoad` you could say `requests => <number of keep-alive requests per connection>`. You could also implement the [polling mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling).

Comment: ahhh...  i'm doing requests, not handling them!

Comment: so, as i already mentioned, i'm building a client, not a server, so, this answer is unfortunately a non-sequitur

Comment: Ah in that case you could use polling to keep polling the server so that it does not time out and await desired response.

Comment: As mentioned, I don't know any perl, so, I was looking for a complete working snippet for what appears to be a quite easy task.  I guess I might instead write this in C with libcurl instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

def deal_with_specal_case(res -> request.response):
    print("oops server error")


# main
url = 'https://www.google.com/?search=foobar'
res = requests.get(url)

while True:
    if res.response_code == '200' and any(mystring in x for x in res.text.splitlines()): break
    else:
        res = requests.get(url)
        if res.response_code > 499:
            deal_with_special_case(res)
            break
```